# Centering a block that has multiple lines of text

Tags: html, css

Here is an example I'm working with:

http://jsfiddle.net/adyjzbuh/18/

Here is the code:

```
<div class="box1">
    <div class="box2">Some text</div>
</div>
<div class="box1">
    <div class="box2">Some more text, actually, 2 lines of textalicious text</div>
</div>
<div class="box1">
    <div class="box3">Some more text, actually, 2 lines of textalicious text</div>
</div>
<div class="box1">
    <div class="box4">Some more text, actually, 2 lines of textalicious text</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.box1 {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.box2 {
    display: table;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
.box3 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
.box4 {
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

As you can see, the first block does exactly what I want. The margins automatically adjust, the block is centered as intended. The issues come when there is multiple lines of text. When I use the same style for the next block with multiple lines of text, the block adjusts the width to 100% of the available space, leaving a big gap on the first line and block not appearing centered.

I tried changing the display to inline-block and table-cell but it does not work (as evidenced by the third and fourth block). I've searched everywhere for solutions and none have worked.

The outer container will always be 300px and the inner block will always have to be flexible and adjust to multi-line text. Any solutions/examples would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

**EDIT** I forgot to mention the client specifically wants the text to align to the left.

Comment: You won't be able to do this with CSS alone, you will need some jQuery/JavaScript.  The CSS rendering engine cannot adjust a width based on the lengths of individual words, which is essentially what you are trying to achieve.  If you try `text-align: justify`, then the extra white space at the end of the first line gets distributed between the words, and the quality of the results will vary.

Comment: Good Question! - I am curious now too

Comment: It's as I thought Marc. I was hoping maybe I was missing something. I'll see if anyone else has any other ideas. If it was me, I'd just center the text, but it's client orders. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would add:

```
text-align: center
```

or

```
text-align:justify
```

instead of:

```
text-align:left
```

Is that what you expected to look like?

Comment: Thank you for the response. My apologies, I forgot to put that the client specifically wants the text to align left. I've edited my original post.

Comment: Is that possible for you to set height of .box1? You could then use transform: translate(-50%, -50%). Like here: https://jsfiddle.net/adyjzbuh/22/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put a max-width: 50%; on your innerboxes. The reason is your solution doesn't really work the way you want is your margins are set to auto, so the margin is calculated of the width. So if say your width would be 50% of the parent container (in this case .box1), the margins are automatically calculated to fill up the other 50%, 25% for each side.

Max-width could fix your problem, the innerboxes are still flexible, but only will take up 50% of the width.

```
.box1 {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.box2 {
    display: table;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! While the solution works for me, my client is very technical and wants it to be this certain way. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are looking for ultimately, [but here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/mikon1982/gwfywa7n/2/), with using table method, like you have, but using

```
display:table;
display:table-cell;
```

accordingly with text aligned in the middle, and centered or left aligned.